# Вставить иконку в QTableWidgetItem

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, gif

Никак не удается вставить иконку в ячейку таблицы, вот примерный код:

```
image = QIcon()
image.addFile('img/image.gif')

item = QTableWidgetItem(image)
self.tableWidget.setItem(1,2, item)
```

Comment: Вы в курсе, что QIcon не умеет в гифки? Скажем, первый кадр гифки покажет, но анимацию нет

Comment: похоже умеет - смотрите первый ответ ниже

Comment: у меня будет обычный статичный рисунок

Comment: это мой ответ :D и он не умеет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У QTableWidgetItem есть метод [setIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setIcon):

```
item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setIcon(image)
```

---

[Полноценный пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/d82fcc96984b7ab1688fe8ee797a0a57b7451585/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/table__cell__icon_image):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Window(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setRowCount(3)

        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                icon = Qt.QIcon()
                icon.addFile('loading.gif')

                item = Qt.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setIcon(icon)

                self.table.setItem(i, j, item)

        main_layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** по просьбе автора выложил пример окна с `QMainWindow`:

```
class Window(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setRowCount(3)

        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                icon = Qt.QIcon()
                icon.addFile('loading.gif')

                item = Qt.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setIcon(icon)

                self.table.setItem(i, j, item)

        main_layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.table)

        central_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
```

Comment: не получается также - APPCRASH

Comment: `item = QTableWidgetItem()`

Comment: спасибо, ваш код работает, только у меня class Window(QMainWindow) - не могли бы вы привести пример для него?

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: спасибо большое братец, вы мне очень помогли - выбираю ваш ответ лучшим